# How do I find out the application version that is currently deployed in OpenShift as a container image?

Tags: docker, openshift

I have succesfully deployed a Spring Boot application in OpenShift as a container image from our private registry. So far, so good. Hoever, I would like to be able to see in the OC which "version" of the application is deployed and I am unable to see how to find that information.
I have added the version as a container label and I can see that the docker label is being read when the image is imported:

```
oc import-image my-app
imagestream.image.openshift.io/my-app imported

Name:                   my-app
Namespace:              my-playground
Created:                46 hours ago
Labels:                 app=my-app
                        app.kubernetes.io/component=my-app
                        app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-app
                        app.kubernetes.io/name=my-app
                        app.kubernetes.io/part-of=my-app-app
Annotations:            openshift.io/image.dockerRepositoryCheck=2022-02-25T10:52:18Z
...
Image Created:  15 minutes ago
...
Exposes Ports:  28888/tcp
Docker Labels:  label=version-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
...
```

But then I have tried in the console GUI and I can't see any information regarding the dockers labels I have added to the container. I can also see them through the oc client with `oc describe istag/my-app:latest` but not in the GUI.

Is there any way I can add the version info somewhere so I can see it easily in the Openshift console? Yes, command line is nice, but why use two tools when one should be enough?

Thank you!

If there is any other place I can put the version information so I can see it from the GUI, I'm all ears!

Comment: can you please elaborate on your use case? are deploying multiple versions in the same namespace? usually, when that's the case you'd add a post-fix for the branches, like dev or test. if you just want A way to check the version for an application I don't think there is one for on the fly but you could check the yaml files of the image stream and\or the deployment\DC

Comment: Hi @NoamYizraeli, I'm not deploying multiple versions separately, but I just wanted to find out which version is deployed, as the docker images are tagged with latest and the specific version.
You can go to Edit Deployment and check there the ImageStream tag deployed and if it is latest, guess that's the last one, but yeah, the GUI in this case is not really handy.
In the end, what I did was to develop a small script in bash that queries the ImageStream tag of the deployment and then the DockerLabels of that ImageStream tag to tell me which version is deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is that it is not easily visible in the web console. There is no place in the console where you can see the Docker Labels of the images of an Image Stream, so...
What I did was create this little handy script that queries the descriptor and then the image stream to display the docker labels

```
#! /bin/bash
DEPLOYMENT_IMAGE_STREAM=`oc describe deployment/$1 | grep ImageStreamTag | grep -Po "$1\:[^\"]+"`
echo "Deployment specifies image stream: $DEPLOYMENT_IMAGE_STREAM"
DOCKER_LABEL_VERSION=`oc describe istag/$DEPLOYMENT_IMAGE_STREAM | grep "Docker Labels" | awk '{ print \$3 }' | cut -d'=' -f2`
echo "Version specified in the image stream: $DOCKER_LABEL_VERSION"
```

Note that this is a crude script that is specific to our case, as we just add one Docker label and know where to cut the lines. If you need to use it, you migth need to adjust the awks and cut options a bit.
If you are using a Deployment Config instead of a simple Deployment, you need to change deployment/$1 with dc/$1 in the first line.
Cheers!